# Stylus in meteor compile error

Tags: meteor, package, stylus

I am getting a a Stylus compile error in a few lines in my stylus code, this is happening after a meteor update. The error is `Path must be a string. Received undefined` I am using [this](https://atmospherejs.com/mquandalle/stylus) stylus package. I am running meteor `1.6.1.1` I have updated all my packages.

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-stylus/issues/18)?

Comment: Oh, no I hadn't I did try replacing with the stylus package and got some other bugs, I will try again and possibly post those errors if I'm stuck